# Why sometimes occur error: java.lang.runtimeexception: takepicture failed?

Tags: android, android-camera

I create a camera app and Take Picture by AutoFocus:

```
private AutoFocusCallback _pfnAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        //camera.autoFocus(null);
        camera.takePicture(_pfnShutterCallback, _pfnRawPictureCallback, mPicture);
    }
};
```

Sometime occur error and crash app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1828)
    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1773)
    at com.example.CameraTest$2.onAutoFocus(CameraTest.java:1835)
    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1273)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

If start app again, It can take Picture working ok.

Why sometimes occur error:  `java.lang.runtimeexception: takepicture failed?`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if auto focus succeeded:

```
private AutoFocusCallback _pfnAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        if(success){
        camera.takePicture(_pfnShutterCallback, _pfnRawPictureCallback, mPicture);
        }
    }
};
```